# Are British farmers not allowed to slaughter and eat their own animals?

Tags: united-kingdom, animals, agriculture

At about 19:30 in the film [Dark River (2018) - Tubi](https://tubitv.com/movies/582797/dark-river), a sheep has broken its leg.
the farmer pays a vet £20 to kill it and then hires a knacker to dispose of the body.

The farmer later shoots, skins, and guts a wild rabbit, so it's not an issue of being squeamish.

Is there some law in the UK that prevents the obvious action: the farmer's slaughtering the animal and having it for dinner?

Comment: I am sure someone will come and give the details, but effectively the answer is yes  because of animal welfare.  [The government guidance is here](https://www.gov.uk/government/collections/welfare-of-animals-at-the-time-of-killing), see particularly [Slaughter poultry, livestock and rabbits for home consumption](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/slaughter-poultry-livestock-and-rabbits-for-home-consumption) and [Slaughtering poultry, rabbits and hares on farms for small-scale suppliers](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/slaughtering-poultry-rabbits-and-hares-on-farms-for-small-scale-suppliers)

Comment: @User65535 it looks to me like the answer is in fact "no, farmers _are_ allowed to slaughter their livestock for home consumption but they need specialized equipment."  This includes a gun with "correct power and calibre of cartridge for the type of animal."  We know the farmer has a gun, so my guess is that the family doesn't like mutton, or has enough in the freezer, or perhaps butchering a sheep is more work than the farmer wants to undertake.  Or maybe, given the £20 paid to the vet, the farmer's gun doesn't work with the ammunition needed for a sheep.

Comment: It is quite possible that a shotgun would not be approved as an appropriate slaughter device.

Comment: Does the farmer hire the vet *specifically* to kill the animal?  Or is it that the vet is originally called to examine / diagnose / treat the animal, but determines that it is incurable and so euthanizes the animal at that point?

Comment: @NateEldredge, yes, it was for that specific purpose. The broken bone is obvious, and the farmer is experienced enough to know that treatment isn't a reasonable option. (Students at vet colleges end up in one of two ideological streams: pets have a sentimental value that outweighs the cost of treatment; and treatment cost exceeds replacement cost.)